# Description environment within footnote

Tags: lists, footnotes, description

Using a description within a footnote puts a line break after the footnote number instead of starting in the same line.

[image: Footnote]

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside, draft]{Report}

\begin{document}

Text\footnote{\begin{description} \item[Item 1] Description of item 1 \end{description}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a more elegant solution, however this works:

Putting the description within a minipage:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside, draft]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
Line with note\footnote{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{1\paperwidth}%
\begin{description}
\item [{Item}] Description
\item [{Item}] Description
\item [{Item}] Description
\end{description}
%
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to fail if you have more than one footnote with the same format though.